# Unable to center image with position absolute

Tags: css

On my image I have a progress bar in svg that wraps around image. How ever when I try and center the image it does not go into the middle. The svg does but not the image.

Question: How is it possible to make the img and svg be in middle of column.

Codepen Example [Here](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/qaLNXv)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="column-module">
                <div class="profile-module-info">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="profile-avatar">
                                <div class="image">
                                <img data-src="holder.js/154x154" width="154" height="154" class="img-circle img-thumbnail" />
                                </div>
                                <svg class="mi-progressbar">
                                    <circle id="circle" r="25%" cx="50%" cy="50%" stroke-width="10"></circle>
                                </svg>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="profile-statistics">
                            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                                <li></li>
                                <li></li>
                                <li></li>
                                <li></li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background-color: #F0F0F0;

}

.container  {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.column-module {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    min-height: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08), 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.column-module .column-module-heading {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    padding: 20px;
}


.column-module .column-module-heading {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
    padding: 20px;
}

.column-module .column-module-heading .column-module-title {
    color: #1f2836;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


.btn-group{
    display: flex;
}

.profile-avatar {
   border: 1px solid #bec0c2;
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: -2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.profile-avatar svg {
    position: relative;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    fill: none;
    stroke: #337ab7;
    stroke-dasharray: 0 0;
}

.profile-avatar img {
      position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

svg circle.progress-bar-success{
    stroke:#5cb85c;
}
svg circle.progress-bar-info{
    stroke:#5bc0de
}
svg circle.progress-bar-warning{
    stroke:#f0ad4e;
}
svg circle.progress-bar-danger{
    stroke:#d9534f;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this:

```
.profile-avatar img {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[Codepen Fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjPqzj)